Rotational Raman peak removal using an FFT
Outline
I have some Raman spectroscopy data that contains features that I want to remove. I'll point them out in the figure below:

Here you can see two sets of peaks that I am interested in, with the right set annotated. The main "vibrational" peaks (blue) I want to preserve, and the accompanying "rotational" peaks (red) that I want to remove with some kind of filter. There is also a potential for other vibrational peaks to appear (green) among the rotational peaks that I also want to preserve.
What I've tried
My idea is that, because the rotational peaks appear to have a regular frequency somewhat similar to a sinc function, I can remove them by taking an FFT, removing the associated frequencies, and retrieving the filtered spectrum with an IFFT.
Here is the result of my attempt:

This figure shows a crop of the region annotated in the previous figure. Hopefully the figure legends are clear, but I will point out some key things:

I first subtracted the minimum value for the cropped region, to make the filtering process simpler
I have used a low-pass filter (LPF) to remove the Gaussian-like shape from the FFT (bottom; red) of the original spectrum (top; black) to produce the filtered FFT (bottom; green)
I perform an IFFT on the filtered FFT to produce a spectrum containing my rotational peaks (top; green), and then subtract it from my original spectrum to obtain my filtered result (top; magenta).

You can see an overlaid comparison of the original and filtered spectra below:

Thoughts/Observations
As you can see my filtering attempt is not perfect, however the result of the LPF and IFFT does seem to do a reasonable job at recreating the rotational peaks and not the vibrational peaks, and the peak of interest (encircled green in the first figure) is made more prominent.
The main issues from what I can see are:

The LPF has not perfectly fit to the Gaussian-like shape (although I am hesitant to fine-tune this value as then the process will lose some generalisability), this has caused the rotational peaks to not be fully removed.
The filtered spectrum seems to have added a slight sine wave across the filtered regions, which I've roughly annotated
The left filtered region is overall lower in intensity than before, which could be easily fixed with an additional step afterwards, but I think it could prove unnecessary with some improvements to the filtering process

Code & Data
I'll post a code snippet for how I have applied my filter:
import numpy as np
from scipy.fft import fft, fftshift, ifft, ifftshift

# Make a copy of the spectrum
spectrum_filtered = np.copy(spectrum_avg)
# Manually define some regions to be cropped and filtered
crop_regions = [[379, 479], [620, 791]]
for crop_region in crop_regions:
    # Crop the spectrum
    crop_left, crop_right = crop_region
    crop = np.copy(spectrum_avg[crop_left:crop_right])
    
    # Subtract the minimum value
    min_val = np.min(crop)
    crop -= min_val
    
    # FFT
    crop_fft = np.abs(fftshift(fft(crop)))
    
    # Fit the baseline using a low-pass filter
    fit = butter_filter(crop_fft, cutoff=3, fs=crop_fft.size, order=5, btype='lowpass')
    
    # Remove the baseline, then perform an IFFT (this holds the rotational peaks)
    crop_fft_fit = crop_fft - fit
    crop_ifft = np.abs(ifftshift(ifft(crop_fft_fit)))
    
    # Subtract the rotational peaks
    crop_filtered = crop - crop_ifft

    # Replace the cropped region with the filtered spectrum (re-adding the minimum value)
    spectrum_filtered[crop_left:crop_right] = crop_filtered + min_val

Here is a pastebin link to the example spectrum: https://pastebin.com/HHuJJXxL
I'm happy to clarify anything should it prove necessary. I would greatly appreciate any feedback, criticism, or suggestions on how to improve this method!
(Note: I have been redirected to post my question here, as I was unaware of the existence of this site, so my apologies for any problems with my question's formatting! For reference, here is a link to my original question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79227592/sinc-like-feature-removal-with-an-fft you can also see an interesting answer from user "Martin Brown" with an alternative approach to solving this problem)

What a SO commenter said about your question w.r.t programming per se (which they believe is a primary SO topic) may be true, but I doubt that your question is better suited for dsp.SE. It may become a signal processing question when you clarify the SP context of your analysis: what scientific evidence do you want to glean from your spectra and why does it require to erase essential part of your raw data? If your ultimate goal is sort of a threshold alarm on vibrational peaks (like using radiation absorption troughs in non-destructive testing), how do weak peaklets interfere with this?

@V.V.T Thank you for the reply! The desire to remove the rotational peaks/lines comes from the increased SNR of my spectrometer picking these up, however the scientific value of the rotational lines (e.g. the temperature information) is unwanted, and instead may confuse the end user of my software--who may not have a complete understanding of Raman spectroscopy--and so I would like to remove them. This would help to better identify and analyse independent vibrational lines that can appear among these sets of rotational lines (such as the one I have encircled in green).

Among many uses of Raman spectrometers I couldn't think of any making these instruments useful for a person familiar with SNR but ignorant about the rotational degrees of freedom so that their appearance in spectrum plots may confuse one. If there are, maybe you should consider the software output containing no plots at all, only printouts with text and figures, shouldn't you? Are you familiar with 'PGOPHER, a program for rotational, vibrational and electronic spectra' (https://pgopher.chm.bris.ac.uk/)? For the record: rotational oscillations are not the noise and do not decrease SNR figures.
